# Отсортировать SQL выдачу

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый день, можете подсказать как мне отсортировать выдачу MySQL по количеству совпадений? К примеру есть запрос

```
SELECT * FROM `content` WHERE `text` LIKE "%hi%" AND `text` LIKE "%bro%"
```

Надо сделать так, что бы выдача была по убыванию ( то бишь там где больше всего `bro` и `hi` - самое первое, где меньше всего - самое последнее ). Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate

Comment: @norbornen а как это относится к моей проблеме? Функция же показывает вхождение а не количество совпадений.

Comment: `SELECT word FROM words WHERE word LIKE '%searchstring1%'  and word LIKE '%searchstring2%' ORDER BY (LOCATE('searchstring1', word) + LOCATE('searchstring2', word))`

Comment: @JoneGreen, сколько раз в строке 'aaaaa' встречается подстрока 'aa'?

Comment: @minamoto ты собираешься полнотекстовый поиск насоветовать? :)

Comment: @norbornen, полнотекстовый поиск тут ни при чем. А ваш запрос считает совсем не то, о чем спрашивает автор.

Comment: SELECT (length(text) - length(replace(text,'hi','')) / 2) + (length(text) - length(replace(text,'bro','')) / 3) AS OrderField FROM content WHERE text LIKE "%hi%" AND `text` LIKE "%bro%" ORDER BY OrderField

Comment: @santavital, хорошая идея, я сам не догадался, но есть один нюанс - я не зря задал вопрос про количество нахождений. Если считать, что количество равно 2, то ваш запрос сработает. Если 4-м (1-2 символ, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5), то не сработает, порядок сортировки будет не верным. В любом случае, я бы на вашем месте оформил это как ответ.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT *, 
       (length(text) - length(replace(text,'hi','')) / 2) + 
       (length(text) - length(replace(text,'bro','')) / 3) AS OrderField 
FROM content 
WHERE text LIKE "%hi%" AND text LIKE "%bro%" 
ORDER BY OrderField
```

Comment: сделайте отступы, плз.

Comment: Думаю, на 2 и 3 надо делить разность между длинами, а не длину после замены. Тогда получится как раз количество вхождений для каждой подстроки: `(length(text) - length(replace(text,'hi',''))) / 2 +
 (length(text) - length(replace(text,'bro',''))) / 3`